# Search not returning complete results from list

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, search-results, sharepoint-search, pnp

I have a list with the following columns:

- Title
- ContactID
- ContactForename
- ContactSurname
- ContactAddress
- ContactDOB
- ContactAge
- ContactGender

I also have a Search page which is using the V4 PNP Modern Search webparts from Github, configured to return item from this list only. The list has been populated with 10 lines of dummy data for testing purposes so a complete line looks like this:

| Title | ContactID | ContactForename | ContactSurname | ContactAddress | ContactDOB | ContactAge | ContactGender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mr | 0001 | John | Smithe | 100 test Rd | 01/01/00 | 22 | Male |

**Desired behavior:** When I search for either a complete or partial match of the contents of any of the fields in the Search Box, The entire list item will be returned in the Search Results.

**Current Behavior:** When I search for a complete or partial match of ContactID, ContactForename or ContactSurname, I get no results but if I search on any other field the entire list item comes back with all fields populated including ContactID, ContactForename and ContactSurname.

The data is in the list and can be retrieved but three of the columns are not being queried. I have 3 other lists like this with different different column titles but an identical setup and they all behave properly.

**Things I Have Already Tried:**
Reindex the list
Republish the Content Type
Delete and recreate the search webparts
Delete and recreate the entire search page

Can anyone think of anything else I can try? I'm expecting the solution to be something really simple that's slipped my mind.

Comment: Did you make sure that ContactID, ContactForename and ContactSurname crowled properties are mapped to managed properties? If you didn't do it - you won't be able to search using these columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect, your ContactID, ContactForename or ContactSurname crawled properties are not connected to managed properties. If that's the case then you can try the following:

- Navigate to the Search Settings
- Find your crawled property. i.e. ContactID. Map this property to one of the managed free properties. Does not matter which one.
- Mark the managed property and **queriable** and **searchable**.
- Create an alias for the managed property. For example, call it ContactID
- Make some change in your list and reindex this list.
- Wait for 15-60 minutes and try searching using your alias
- Repeat for the rest of the properties.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thankyou.