# Content Search not returning list columns

Tags: content-search-web-part, sharepoint-library

Noob here. Still using SP 2010 here - company stuck in the dark ages.

I am getting to grips with content search and have successfully pulled items in to my Webpart based on crawling a library for items with a specific keyword. That in itself was a small victory!

In my library I've added a column called URL and added links. I want that to be the link in the **LinkURL** field in the Property Mappings but it isn't allowing "URL" to be found in the available dropdown list.

Any advice? I'm totally handcuffed with site settings due to my company policy so if it involves changing anything like that I'm stuck...

Thanks

Comment: Have you identified the column's corresponding crawled property and mapped it a managed property?

Comment: Sorry how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As @Callum mentioned in his comment, you need to find the crawled property and map it to managed property. More info: [Search not returning complete results from list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/300751/search-not-returning-complete-results-from-list)

1. Navigate to the Search Settings.
2. Find your crawled property, in this case, "URL".
3. Map this property to one of the managed free properties. It doesn’t matter which one.
4. Mark the managed property as queryable and searchable.
5. Create an alias for the managed property, "URL".
6. Make some change in your list and reindex this list.